# How to share cookie between Webview and Retrofit2 Okhttp3

Tags: kotlin, android-webview, retrofit2

I have a site with 2 requests:

**The first is to see a basket containing ingredients (without the need to login)**

```
GET https://www.ah.nl/mijnlijst2
```

**The second is the request to insert an item in the basket.**

```
POST https://www.ah.nl/common/api/basket/v2/add
{
    "items": [{
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 395948
    }]
}
```

In my App I've done 3 things:

1. Initialize the cookie using a hidden webview:

   ```
   initializeWebView(binding.webView, "https://www.ah.nl/mijnlijst2")

   var myCookie = ""

   @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled")
   fun initializeWebView(webView: WebView, url: String?) {
       val settings = webView.settings
       settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
       settings.builtInZoomControls = false
       settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
       settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false)
       settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
       webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
       webView.loadUrl(url)

       webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

           override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView?, url: String) {
               super.onPageFinished(webView, url)

               val syncManager =
                   CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webView?.context)
               val cookieManager: CookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
               cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true)

               if (cookieManager.getCookie(url)!= null) {
                   val cookie: String = cookieManager.getCookie(url)
                   myCookie = cookie
                   Timber.d("Cookie = $myCookie")
               }

               syncManager.sync()
           }
       }

       webView.loadUrl(url)
   }
   ```

2: Insert an ingredient:

```
val response = api.insertIngredient(WebViewManager.myCookie, ingredients).execute()

interface AHApi {

    @Headers(
        "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
    )
    @POST("common/api/basket/v2/add")
    fun insertIngredient(
        @Header("cookie") cookie: String,
        @Body ingredients: AhIngredientRequest
    ): Call<ResponseBody>
}

data class AhIngredientRequest(

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("items")
    val items: List<AhItem>
)

data class AhItem(

    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Long = 0L,

    @SerializedName("quantity")
    var quantity: Long = 1L
)

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAHApi(context: Context): AHApi{
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    } else {
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE)
    }

    val timeout = 30L
    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .followRedirects(false)
        .build()

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(context.getString(R.string.ah_api))
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create().asLenient())
        .client(client)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(AHApi::class.java)
}
```

3. Startup the item list in the webview:

   ```
   class WebviewFragment : Fragment() {

   private lateinit var binding: FragmentWebviewBinding

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false)
       binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rootView)!!

       WebViewManager.initializeWebView(binding.webView, "https://www.ah.nl/mijnlijst2")

       return rootView
   }
   }
   ```

   - the OkHttp3 response gives back a 200 OK.
   - The WebView remains empty, 0 items. I expect my inserted item to be in there because I shared my cookie with `setAcceptThirdPartyCookies`.
   - But: 
     when I first manually add an ingredient, 
     and then click the shopping list 
     and then go back to my App,
     and load the webview again,
     from this moment on everything works.

So it appears that manually initializing the cookie by going to

- POST https://www.ah.nl/common/api/basket/v2/add
- https://www.ah.nl/mijnlijst2

Works, but when I do it programmatically, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the `cookieManager` to the Retrofit HTTP client (OkHttp).

You can do so using [`JavaNetCookieJar`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/JavaNetCookieJar.kt) from [`okhttp-urlconnection`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-urlconnection) package, a wrapper class that delegates to [`java.net.CookieHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager):

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.6.0"

val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cookieJar(JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
    .build()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(httpClient)
    .build()
```